# How to show count label on selected UICollectionview cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CalendarCollectionView, which shows up as monthly calendar similar like iOS Calendar. So on that Calendar i have to show the PreselectedPeriod dates which user has already selected before. But i also need to show a label as a count on these cells (let's assume if user has Preselected values as 23,24,25,26 so on these dateCell user should also see 1,2,3,4 as right corner label respectively).
How can i do that?[image: Please refer to image attached for more understanding]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already selected dates you can use the following logic with little modifications according to your requirement.

You can declare the helper variables

```
// This is your list of pre-selected dates
let preselectedPeriod = [3,12,13,14,16,17,18,29,30]

// Counter variable to increase your selected dates range
var count = 0
```

Your `cellForIntemAt` looks like this.
**Note:** Here I have used the `indexPath` as the calendar date

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.dateLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row+1)"
    cell.rangeIndicatorLabel.textColor = .white
    cell.card.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.card.layer.masksToBounds = true
    
    if preselectedPeriod.contains(indexPath.row+1) {
        count += 1
        cell.card.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        cell.dateLabel.textColor = .white
        cell.rangeIndicatorLabel.text = "\(count)"
    }else{
        cell.dateLabel.textColor = .black
        cell.card.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.rangeIndicatorLabel.text = ""
    }
    return cell
}
```

[image]